# Pass a variable from Javascript to AMP Script or SSJS

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, ssjs, cloudpage

Is it possible to pass a variable from Javascript to AMP Script or SSJS? The reason is I need to use Javascript libraries to generate a variable which I need to use in SSJS to make an API call.

Answer (score 4):

Common question, likely a duplicate. But anyway:

- Ampscript is server-side.
- Server-sided JavaScript is server-side.

vs.

- "normal" Javascript is client-side.

**Server-side means, in plain terms:**

To execute the code, the page needs to (re-)load.
The client (frontend) never gets to see or change the code. Only the server serving the page interpreted it and "that ship has sailed" by the time you / a user sees the final page.

**Client-side means:**

The code can execute after page load (e.g. on click). The client also can see or tamper with the code. Bad for API calls that rely on secret credentials.

So: your API call, as you say, needs to be server-side.

But:

Can something that happens after page load (client side script) manipulate other code that has already been executed earlier (server side script)?

No. Just "order of execution"-wise, it cannot work.

What you need to do is:

Send the result of your client-side javascript to a page that loads and executes serverside script like AMPScript/ SSJS on load. That page can send the API call.

This can be a separate Page (typically a handler page that you can set up as code resource - costs no supermessage) or your original page, but then you'll need to set your page up so that it send the data back to the page itself.

A nice  "best of both worlds" approach (don't make the user leave the page, but send the data somewhere else for server-side handling) is AJAX.

I keep reusing this code bit for the frontend (which I've stolen somewhere else - appreciated, unknown contributor). It relies on a jquery library for the AJAX call. Your handler / backend you'll of course need to create separately using AMPScript / SSJS.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style>
        table {
            border-collapse: collapse;
        }

        table, th, td {
            border: 1px solid black;
        }

    </style>    
</head>
<body>
    <form id='form1'>
        <div><input type='text' name='name' placeholder='Name' /></div>
        <div><input type='text' name='email' placeholder='Email' /></div>
        <div><input type='text' name='number' placeholder='Mobile Number' /></div>
        <div><input type='submit' value='Submit' /></div>
    </form>
    <div id='response'></div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js "></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){

            $('#form1').submit(function(){

                // show that something is loading
                $('#response').html("<b>Loading response...</b>");

                // Call ajax for pass data to other place
                $.ajax({

                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'YOURHANDLERCLOUDPAGEURLHERE',
                    data: $(this).serialize() // form values

                }).done(function(data){ // executed when response is returned

                    // show the response
                    $('#response').html(data);

                }).fail(function() { // executed when post failed

                    alert( "Submission failed" );

                });

                // to prevent page refresh
                return false;

            });
        });
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for sharing the snippet it is very useful!