# Javascript variable not being passed to ampscript when using Save button. The form should not be submitted

Tags: marketing-cloud, javascript, ampscript, cloudpage, variable

```
<form>
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<button id="button" class="button" onclick="returnData()">Next</button>
</form>


<script runat="server">
  function returnData() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   }
    
     Platform.Variable.SetValue(@email, "email");

  </script>

%%=v(@email)=%%
```

I am trying to pass a javascript variable to ampscript but it's not working.  I'm not submitting the form but adding a saved button to capture the email.  Below is the code I used.  Where am I going wrong?  My form is in the comment section.

```
<form>
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<button id="button" class="button" onclick="returnData()">Next</button>
</form>
```

Comment: <form>
<input id="firstName" name="firstName" type="text" placeholder="First Name">
<input id="lastName" name="lastName" type="text" placeholder="Last Name">
<input id="email" name="email" type="text" placeholder="Email">
<button id="button" class="button" onclick="returnData()">Next</button>
</form>


<script runat="server">
  function returnData() {
    var email = document.getElementById("email").value;
   }
    
     Platform.Variable.SetValue(@email, "email");

  </script>

%%=v(@email)=%%

Comment: Comments are for clarification, not question content. Use the `{}` format option to format your code correctly while editing your question. I've edited your question this time, click [edit] to see what the source looks like.

Comment: You are going wrong when you choose the tool: serverside (SSJS) cannot do client-side jobs as it's executed before client-side actions ("button is pressed"). Same goes for AMPScript which you use to display. To display on page, you have to use client-side JS, to get data to backend using SSJS capabilities, a (separate) handler page.

https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/400224/pass-a-variable-from-javascript-to-amp-script-or-ssjs/400325#400325